# How to populate a woocommerce custom field from a specific field in an embedded gravity form?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, hook-woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a gravity form within a product so when you purchase the product, the form has to be filled out. I am trying to take some data from one of the form fields and assign this data to a woocommerce order custom field.

The plugins, forms, and custom fields are set up I'm just struggling to find the correct hook/way of automatically filling in the custom field when the order's placed.

The plugins being used are:

- Woocommerce
- WooCommerce Admin Custom Order Fields
- Gravity Forms
- Gravity Forms Product Add-ons

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding something like this to your functions.php: (make sure you read the notes comment which shows you where to add your WooCommerce Admin Custom Order Fields along with your Gravity Forms entry field id

```
//Get Gravity Form Info into Woocoomerce custom Fields
    add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'wc_add_gf_to_woo' );
    function wc_add_gf_to_woo( $order_id ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        $cart_items = $order->get_items();
        foreach( $cart_items as $item => $item_meta) { 
            $linked_entry=$item_meta->get_meta( '_gravity_forms_history')["_gravity_form_linked_entry_id"]; 
            if (isset($linked_entry) && !empty($linked_entry)){
                $entry_id = $linked_entry;
                $entry = GFAPI::get_entry( $entry_id );
                update_post_meta( $order_id, '_wc_acof_{id}', $entry['40'] );//replace {id} with the id of custom field (see here https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-admin-custom-order-fields/#section-10) && Replace '40' with the Gravity Form field id that contains the info you need
            }
        }
    };
```